# How is “progress per hour” calculated?

Tags: bitcoin-core

How is “progress per hour” calculated?

[image: progress per hour]

What would be the shell script code to return this result?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but the code calculating the progress increase per hour is in [`ModalOverlay::tipUpdate()`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/ce3b75690d10426e97d087ca600140a19bf180b7/src/qt/modaloverlay.cpp#L90-L117)